# Could not understand the output

Tags: java

In the below code different three outputs are coming depending upon the hashcode value generated for the object after running multiple times

```
Output1
collection.A@1
0
collection.A@0
0
true


Output2
collection.A@1
0
collection.A@0
1
true

Output3
collection.A@1
1
collection.A@1
1
true
```

I am not able to understand the three different outputs that are coming , 
For e.g Output3  why two objects are added if the hashcode is same of them and equals returns true
Simliarly I am not able to understand the Output1 & 2

---

```
 public class A {

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        long l=Math.round(Math.random());
        return (int)l;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
        return true;
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){

        Set<A> h=new HashSet<A>();
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            h.add(new A());

        for (A a : h) {
            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println(a.hashCode());
        }
        System.out.println(h.contains(new A()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `A.hashCode` method returns a random value each time it is called. This will confuse the `HashSet` and you'll see unpredictable results.

Comment: You cannot check hash code, because the one has unpredictable value. You add with one hash code to the set, read with another one. Store the generated hash code in the A constructor.

Comment: This code is inherently broken. `hashCode` cannot be chosen random everytime.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, your code breaks the contract of `hashCode()`.

One of the rules to implement `hashCode` is that this must always be true:

```
obj.hashCode() == obj.hashCode()
```

But in your case, this isn't. Every time `hashCode` is called, the result can be different from that of the previous call. This is because `Math.random()` returns a different value each time.

How come only two objects are added to the set?

Because only objects with different hash codes can be added to a `HashSet`. If an object with a hash code of 1 is added, another object with hash code of 1 cannot be added.

And since your `hashCode` method can only return two different integers - 1 and 0, at most 2 objects can be added.

In output 3, why do I see two objects of the same hash code in the set?

```
collection.A@1
1
collection.A@1
1
true
```

That is because your `hashCode` method may return different values every time you call it. Maybe when the two objects are added to the set, their `hashCode` method return different values. But by the time you call it, they change to the same value.

Anything can happen, ya know!

P.S. I hope this is not production code...

Answer (score 1):

Because your `Math.round(Math.random());` always return 0 or 1. If you need larger range of random values, It should be like `Math.round(Math.random()*10000);` 
You have to override `toString()` method as well in the Class A.

Add following method to Class `A`, or can modify it as your own.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Class A";

}
```

Also change your `hashCode()` method as follows and try.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    long l=Math.round(Math.random()*10000);
    return (int)l;

}
```

Comment: From the `hashcode()` contract: `Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer`. Random is not exactly `same`.

Answer (score 1):

> For e.g Output3 why two objects are added if the hashcode is same

Since the hashcode can be different each time you check it the strangeness of the results are to be expected.

If all 100 objects return the same hashcode (pairwise) when they are inserted then the set will contain only one object. The probability of this is `0.5^99` or almost 0.

When you print the result, you generate new hashcodes. The value you print is independent of the values used in the comparisons during insertion.

Try remembering the generated hashcode value in a field and have each object return the same value each time and the result will be the same every time.

Answer (score 0):

bcoz of `Math.random()`

> The Math.random()  returns a pseudorandom double greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0