# HashMap methods not understanding how they are called

Tags: java, hashmap

I really don't understand from the below code how the get() methods, set() methods and toString() are called. Could someone explain me ?

The whole point here is after seeing the output I don't understand how the tostring method has been called. I don't see anything explicitly being called.

```
public class MyDuplicateKeyEx {

    public static void main(String a[]){

        HashMap<Price, String> hm = new HashMap<Price, String>();
        hm.put(new Price("Banana", 20), "Banana");
        hm.put(new Price("Orange", 30), "Orange");
        printMap(hm);
        Price key = new Price("Banana", 20);
        System.out.println("Adding duplicate key...");
        hm.put(key, "Grape");
        System.out.println("After adding dulicate key:");
        printMap(hm);
    }

    public static void printMap(HashMap<Price, String> map){

        Set<Price> keys = map.keySet();
        for(Price p:keys){
            System.out.println(p+"==>"+map.get(p));
        }
    }
}

class Price{

    private String item;
    private int price;

    public Price(String itm, int pr){
        this.item = itm;
        this.price = pr;
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        int hashcode = 0;
        hashcode = price*20;
        hashcode += item.hashCode();
        return hashcode;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (obj instanceof Price) {
            Price pp = (Price) obj;
            return (pp.item.equals(this.item) && pp.price == this.price);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }
    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "item: "+item+"  price: "+price;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
item: Apple  price: 40==>Apple
item: Orange  price: 30==>Orange
item: Banana  price: 20==>Banana
Adding duplicate key...
After adding dulicate key:
item: Apple  price: 40==>Apple
item: Orange  price: 30==>Orange
item: Banana  price: 20==>Grape
```

Thanks !!

Comment: String concatenation with `+` makes calls to the `toString` methods of the concatenated objects.

Comment: **Don't** use mutable types as keys in `HashMap`.

Comment: I think it is better to use String(immutable) as key and Price as value of the Map.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, there is no explicit call to `toString`. But under the hood, that is what Java is doing. When seeing `p+"==>"+map.get(p)`, Java is doing `p.toString()+"==>"+map.get(p).toString()`. That is why you can concatenate strings and objects without problems.

Additionally, a better way of iterating through the key/values of a Map is:

```
public static void printMap(HashMap<Price, String> map) {
    for (Map.Entry<Price, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "==>" + entry.getValue())
    }
}
```

When using a HashMap with user-defined objects as keys, you must be **very** careful that you do **never** modify the fields used to compute the `hashCode` if they are present in the map. This is why you'll often see that *final* fields should be used to compute it. With a large program, this avoids lots of unnecessary mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is no explicit `toString`! Java does this implicitly for you! You should thank him, ya know.

The magic lies behind this code:

```
p+"==>"+map.get(p)
```

Here, `p` is a `Price` and `map.get(p)` is a `String`. So the above is basically adding a price to a string, then add another string to the result.

When Java wants to add any object to a string, it calls that object's `toString` to convert that object to `String` *first*. Otherwise, how can a price be added to a string, right?

Tip:

**Never use objects which hash code can change as keys of a hash map.** I have actually seen a person who was very extreme and he implemented the `hashCode` method with `Math.random()`! Here's the post: [Could not understand the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980533/could-not-understand-the-output/36980979#36980979) And asked why can a hash map store things with the same hash code.

So to avoid that confusion, *please* don't use mutable objects as keys. Just remove those setters and you'll be fine.